# Template issue in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I try to use template for defining some class as follows:

.h

```
template <class T>
class QVecTemp
{
public:
    static QVector<QVector<T>> SplitVector<T>(QVector<T>, int);
private:
};
```

.cpp

```
    #include "QVecTemp.h"

template <class T>
QVector<QVector<T>> QVecTemp::SplitVector<T>(QVector<T> items, int clustNum)
{
    QVector<QVector<T>> allGroups = new QVector<QVector<T>>();

    //split the list into equal groups
    int startIndex = 0;
    int groupLength = (int)qRound((float)items.count() / (float)clustNum);
    while (startIndex < items.count())
    {
        QVector<T> group = new QVector<T>();
        group.AddRange(items.GetRange(startIndex, groupLength));
        startIndex += groupLength;

        //adjust group-length for last group
        if (startIndex + groupLength > items.count())
        {
            groupLength = items.Count - startIndex;
        }

        allGroups.Add(group);
    }

    //merge last two groups, if more than required groups are formed
    if (allGroups.count() > clustNum && allGroups.count() > 2)
    {
        allGroups[allGroups.count() - 2].append(allGroups.last());
        allGroups.remove(allGroups.count() - 1);
    }

    return (allGroups);
}
```

On `static QVector<QVector<T>> SplitVector<T>(QVector<T>, int);` I get the following errors:

> error: '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list
>
> error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
>
> error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token

What is actually the problem ? and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static QVector<QVector<T> > SplitVector(QVector<T>, int);
```

You had two errors.

First, in C++03, `>>` cannot be used to close two template argument lists at once, because `>` must be used to close an argument list and `>>` is a different token than two `>`. In C++11, this was fixed. The compiler gave you a wonderful error message for this: `>>` should be `> >`.

Second, member functions of class templates don't have the template arguments of the class after their name. They're not template specializations. The compiler gave you a horrible message for this: after it saw the name `SplitVector` it found a `<`, which can't be there (because `SplitVector` is not a known template name), so the compiler assumed that you were declaring a data member called `SplitVector` and that a `;` must finish the declaration (that's the first error message). Then it looked again at the `<` and still couldn't make sense of it and gave you an even worse message, pretending that anything that could possibly appear at this point in the code must be a name of some sort.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The >> error is fixed, thank you. About the second error, I actually didn't understand in depth how can I solve it.

Comment: I removed both in .h and .cpp and now it gives the following error on QVector<QVector<T> > QVecTemp::SplitVector(QVector<T> items, int clustNum) stroke in .cpp: 
error: 'template<class T> class QVecTemp' used without template parameters

Comment: Should be `template <class T> QVector<QVector<T> > QVecTemp<T>::SplitVector(QVector<T> items, int clustNum)`. The template parameter goes after the class name, because the class is the actual template, the function is just a member.

Answer (score 0):

```
static QVector<QVector<T> > SplitVector<T>(QVector<T>, int);
```

Comment: hey, what you actually mean?

Comment: @Mike what is your c++ compiler?

Comment: @kw I am not quit sure... it is not my PC, but if it helps the environment is Qt 5.1.0 working on mingw48_32

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler told you pretty neatly what the problem is already: prior to C++11, you cannot write the following:

```
some_class<other_class<int>> x; // error
```

because the compiler will interpret the nested `>>` in that line as the `>>` operator. You need an additional space here:

```
some_class<other_class<int> > x; // this is ok
```

Note that newer compilers (with C++11 support) do not have this problem anymore.